# Docker 1.12 reads old line from yml file "volumes" instead of new one

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to execute the instruction 'docker-compose up -d' and it is returning the following error:

```
ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: mkdir /Users/old_usr: permission denied
```

But looking at docker_compose.yml's volume we have the following:

```
volumes:
      - /Users/giancarloguerra/new_usr/mysql_volume:/var/lib/mysql
```

I scoured through my project and there is absolutely no instance of 'old_usr' anywhere. There's just no way it can be sourcing 'old_usr' from my project.

So I don't understand why it's still reading /Users/old_usr when it should be reading the updated line from the yml file. I tried restoring factory settings on docker Mac and also executing docker-compose build once more. Any other suggestions?

Comment: try execute `docker-compose down` before `docker-compose up -d` may be container already created with old configuration

Comment: If the above comment's suggestion doesn't work, please post your Dockerfile, as it may contain something that will help us answer you better.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was an issue with the Atom text editor. For some reason it was not saving changes to the .yml file.